# A data-structure for efficiently indexing thousands of moving points?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

Situation:

I have potentially tens of thousands of moving (2D) points. They affect each other only to a certain radius. They can move from place to place (not teleporting, just flying around the screen, essentially).

Since I have to check for updates every tick, it is rather important to do this efficiently.

My naive solution is to simply create a grid type structure with grid spacing somewhere around the radius of effect and as points move from cell to cell, update which cell they are in. So when I need to do effects checking, I only have to check a point's cell and a few neighboring cells.

I am familiar with quadtree, but I worry that it is a bit more expensive than what I need to do, but I am open to suggestions if this is indeed the correct route.

Also, for added information, this is in Java.

Thanks

Comment: It seems to me that the quadtree saves computation when there are parts of the domain that do not include many or any points, and so do not need to be gridded to the same resolution as parts of the domain that contain many points. However, if the point density is close to uniform across the domain, I don't see that a quadtree would provide an advantage over a regular grid.

Comment: Have you implemented the naive solution to see how much more speed you need?  You can sacrifice accuracy for speed, but should only do so to the degree you require.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i was and for my next project will be in a similar  situation.
I choosed the simple grid variant, because its simpler and faster to implement.
tens of thousands is at the border where an quad tree or k-d tree could make sense. (especially when many cells would be empty)

You should try to test if an grid approach is sufficient. probably it is.